# UICollectionView Animation like Google Play News app

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am interesting in Google play news app in iPhone for its CollectionView animation that popup from bottom. I want to create the same animation effects, but seems like I can't find a good guiding. Is there any tutorials or tips recommended?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

See this man:
http://www.objc.io/issue-12/collectionview-animations.html
In this examle you have many examples and codes are given.

http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html
In the end of this tutorial, you'll have a beautyful animation